# A problem occurred configuring project ':onesignal_flutter

Tags: flutter, onesignal

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':onesignal_flutter'.

> Could not open proj remapped class cache for 2l1gu8tih6yuhcv6muthhswe2 (C:\Users\Asus.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts-remapped\build_16tcpowyxq2c9gqe2ghul7zlm\2l1gu8tih6yuhcv6muthhswe2\proj3e1f7b90744deb65198fe3e2308f45d5).
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\onesignal_flutter-2.6.1\android\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Asus.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts\2l1gu8tih6yuhcv6muthhswe2\proj\proj3e1f7b90744deb65198fe3e2308f45d5).
> > Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':onesignal_flutter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> How can i fix this error

Comment: Show me the 2 build.gradle files